# how to render a datatable based on a list size in jsf using java EL?

Tags: jsf

how to render a datatable based on the list size in jsf using java EL?

Comment: "Based on list size"? Can you elaborate that? The datatable namely does that by default automatically. See also [Using datatables](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/using-datatables.html).

Comment: like how do i use #{someBean.searchLists.size > 2 } , assuming the searchResults is of type List in someBean. I am adding few records voluntarily at the server side , so I wanted to check the size before i display search results. Right now, I am copying the size to a variable in bean and using it as #{someBean.searchListSize > 1}

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Three ways:

1. Add an extra getter.

   ```
   public int getSearchListSize() {
       return searchList.size();
   }
   ```

   with

   ```
   <h:dataTable rendered="#{bean.searchListSize > 2}">
   ```
2. Use [JSTL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/) [`fn:length()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/length.fn.html) function. Install JSTL if not done yet (just drop [jstl-1.2.jar](http://download.java.net/maven/1/jstl/jars/jstl-1.2.jar) in `/WEB-INF/lib`) and declare `fn` taglib in top of JSP as follows:

   ```
   <%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
   ```

   and use it as follows:

   ```
   <h:dataTable rendered="#{fn:length(bean.searchList) > 2}">
   ```
3. Use [JBoss EL](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.2.0.GA/en-US/html/elenhancements.html) ("enhanced EL") as JSF EL implementation instead. It's backwards compatible with standard JSF EL implementation. Drop [jboss-el.jar](http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/org/jboss/seam/jboss-el/2.0.0.GA/jboss-el-2.0.0.GA.jar) in `/WEB-INF/lib` and declare the following in `web.xml`, assuming you're using [Mojarra](http://javaserverfaces.java.net) JSF implementation:

   ```
   <context-param>     
       <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
       <param-value>org.jboss.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>   
   </context-param>
   ```

   This way you can access non-getter methods directly:

   ```
   <h:dataTable rendered="#{bean.searchList.size() > 2}">
   ```

Comment: I haven't tried the 2 and 3 yet. I am using the 1st one. Thanks BalusC.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120526/how-to-display-value-of-listsize-in-jsf-el. (Summary, the third technique should work on most modern servers now, without adding a new JAR.)