# How to display value of List#size() in JSF EL?

Tags: jsf, binding, jsf-2, el

I'd like to know if there's a way to bind the returned value of a method into a JSF component.
I'll explain myself better.
Let's say I have a class like this:

```
public class Document {
   private List<Attachment> attachments;
   //getter and setter here
}
```

this class is exposed to jsf through a registered managed bean in a property called currentDocument, and used in a jsf this way

```
<h:outputText value="#{myManagedBean.currentDocument.attachment.size}" />
```

This isn't correct, I know. But what is the correct way to do this?
Am I supposed to create an attribute on the Document class, let's say numberOfAttachments, and bind to that, or there's a way to bind directly on a method's return value?

Comment: you can use #{myManagedBean.currentDocument.attachments.size()} in order to display size of list.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you're running an EL 2.2 capable container (Tomcat 7, Glassfish 3, JBoss AS 6 or newer, all implementing Servlet 3.0), or are using JBoss EL, then you should be able to invoke non-getter methods by EL:

```
<h:outputText value="#{myManagedBean.currentDocument.attachment.size()}" />
```

An alternative is to use [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) `fn:length()`:

```
<html xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" ...>
...
<h:outputText value="#{fn:length(myManagedBean.currentDocument.attachment)}" />
```

If none of that is possible for you for some reason, then your best bet is to create an EL function yourself

```
<h:outputText value="#{my:size(myManagedBean.currentDocument.attachment)}" />
```

or to add an extra getter method to `#{myManagedBean}` which returns exactly that.

```
<h:outputText value="#{myManagedBean.currentDocumentAttachmentSize}" />
```

#### See also:

- [Invoke direct methods or methods with arguments / variables / parameters in EL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284236/jsf-2-0-method-invocation)