# #{bean.list.size} causes java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "size"

Tags: list, jsf, size, el

Here is my xhtml , i have problem with rendered attribute. I get an error about "size" of my list. I want to render the datatable only if some data found.Couldnt find how to fix it.Thank you for your time.

```
<ui:composition template="/pages/admin/admin.xhtml"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <ui:define name="center">
        <h:form id="updateform">
            <p:growl id="messages"/>
            <p:panel id="pnlUpdateUser" header="#{menu['menu.admin.usermanager.updateuser']}">
                <p:panelGrid columns="2" styleClass="cm_ui-panel-grid">
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{menu['menu.admin.createuser.name']}" styleClass="cm_ui-output-label"/>
                    <p:inputText styleClass="cm_input-text" value="#{userMB.userQuery.name}" required="true" />

                    <p:outputLabel value="#{menu['menu.admin.createuser.surname']}" styleClass="cm_ui-output-label"/>
                    <p:inputText styleClass="cm_input-text" value="#{userMB.userQuery.surname}" />

                    <f:facet name="footer">
                        <p:commandButton value="#{menu.search}" actionListener="#{userMB.queryUsers}" update="pnluserresult"/>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:panelGrid>
            </p:panel>
            <p:panelGrid id="pnluserresult" columns="1"
                    rendered="#{(userMB.users.size eq 0) or (userMB.users.size > 0)} ">
                <p:dataTable id="userresulttable" var="user" value="#{userMB.users}">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <p:outputLabel value="#{menu['menu.admin.updateuser.list']}"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:column headerText="#{menu['menu.admin.createuser.id']}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{user.id}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="#{menu['menu.admin.createuser.name']}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{user.name}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="#{menu['menu.admin.createuser.surname']}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{user.surname}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="#{menu['menu.admin.createuser.grade']}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{user.grade}" />
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
            </p:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Here is my exception stack trace...

```
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "size"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at javax.el.ListELResolver.coerce(ListELResolver.java:157)
    at javax.el.ListELResolver.getValue(ListELResolver.java:70)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:167)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstEqual.getValue(AstEqual.java:37)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstOr.getValue(AstOr.java:37)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstDeferredExpression.getValue(AstDeferredExpression.java:43)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstCompositeExpression.getValue(AstCompositeExpression.java:49)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:187)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.isRendered(UIComponentBase.java:457)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1850)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:79)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:66)
    at org.primefaces.component.layout.LayoutUnitRenderer.encodeEnd(LayoutUnitRenderer.java:49)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:456)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.software.cm.others.filters.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:23)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:655)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: What is `users` in this EL `#{userMB.users.size}`? Is it a collection of some kind? Unfortunately, there is no `getSize()` method yet so that `#{userMB.users.size}` can be evaluated. It should therefore be `#{userMB.users.size()}` instead.

Comment: Thank you @Tiny , problem is solved the way you say.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your problem is that you are missing brackets after #{userMB.users.size}. It should be modified to this:

```
<p:panelGrid id="pnluserresult" columns="1"
                rendered="#{(userMB.users.size() eq 0) or (userMB.users.size() gt 0)} ">
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i was so blind to solve this. @Sapal

Comment: Why didn't you made a remark about the major logical error in the EL expression itself and the alternative EL keyword the OP might be actually looking for?

Comment: @BalusC are you talking about why I did not make a remark about the reason that `#{userMB.users.size}` does not work?

Comment: I find the following answer very helpful for this matter: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7120610/993920

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, like mine it could be necessary to check it another way, I had the same problem but for some reason I still get the:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "size"
```

I'm using Java 8, and JSF 2.0 (Could this be the reason?)

Another way to check is whether or not the list property is null, in the getter be sure to return null if it doesn't have elements, and in JSF Page check like this:

```
rendered="#{(varProcInstance.products != null)}"
```

As I said, this worked for me as the only answer didn't.

Regards,